# How to mock ActivatedRouteSnapshot when unit testing a Resolver

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

I want to write a unit test for my resolver, which needs to take `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` in its constructor like so:

```
export class MyResolver {
  constructor () {
    // ...
  }

  resolve (private route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    callFoo(route.params.val);
  }
};
```

But in my unit test, what's the best way to provide an activated route snapshot with mock data? When I try to create an object with just the properties I need, I get an error that it cannot be cast to ActivatedRouteSnapshot:

```
it('should call foo', inject([MyResolver], async (myResolver: MyResolver) => {
  const mockRoute = {
    params: {
      val: '1234'
    };
  };

  sinon.spy(callFoo);
  myResolver.resolve(mockRoute); // This is the line that errors
  expect(callFoo.calledWith('1234')).to.be.true;
}));
```

**Error:**

```
Type '{ params: { val: string; }; }' cannot be converted to type 'ActivatedRouteSnapshot'.
```

How can I provide a mock ActivatedRouteSnapshot to pass to my resolver?

Answer (score 16):

You have to provide the active route like this:

```
import {TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {SomeResolver} from './some.resolver';
import {ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import {of} from 'rxjs';

describe('SomeResolver', () => {
  let someResolver: SomeResolver;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {
        provide: ActivatedRoute,
        useValue: {snapshot: {paramMap: convertToParamMap({id: 'one-id'})}}
      },
      SomeResolver
    ]
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    heroResolver = TestBed.get(HeroResolver);
    route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
  });

  it('should resolve', (() => {
    someResolver.resolve(route.snapshot);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to get the snapshot via TestBed? TestBed.get() is deprecated btw., so this is not a good solution in my opinion, just to call the service with some mocked variables.

Comment: @FlorianLeitgeb Can you provide an example please?

Comment: Where did you see TestBed.get is deprecated?

Comment: Deprecation warning right here in the documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#get . It says the following:


deprecated from v8.0.0 use Type or InjectionToken This does not use the deprecated jsdoc tag on purpose because it renders all overloads as deprecated in TSLint due to https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4522.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is the prettiest solution, but you can mock the route like this:

```
let route = createSpyObj('Route', ['']);
route.params = {
  val: '1234'
}
```

Comment: I do not think this is ugly or somewhat. It just is, what it needs to be in this case and I prefer it also over the other mentioned solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose is   just to pass the mock to the resolver, it's not necessary to use `createSpyObj`, as suggested in other answers. Also, it would be better to add type safety to the solution:

```js
const mock = <T, P extends keyof T>(obj: Pick<T, P>): T => obj as T;

it('should call foo', () => {
    const route = mock<ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 'params'>({
        params: {
            val: '1234'
        }
    });

    const resolver = createTheResolver();
    const resolverParams = resolver.resolve(route);
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It more simple and direct.

Answer (score 2):

Note you can also simply cast your object as an ActivatedRouteSnapshot if you like:

```
const mockRoute = {paramMap: convertToParamMap({'id': '123'})} as 
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot;

resolver.resolve(mockRoute);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import createSpyObj = jasmine.createSpyObj;

let route = createSpyObj('Route', ['']);
route.params = {
  nameOfParam: 'test'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for my purposes, this was the easiest thing to do (which also allowed me to write to the 'parent' property which is normally read-only:

```
const route = Object.assign({}, ActivatedRouteSnapshot.prototype, {
  params: {
    myParam: 'some_value'
  },
  parent: {
    params: {
      myParentParam: 'some_other_value'
    }
  }
});
```

then you just call your resolver with 'route' like so:

```
it('should do something with my activated route params', (done) => {
const route = Object.assign({}, ActivatedRouteSnapshot.prototype, {
  params: {
    myParam: 'some_value'
  },
  parent: {
    params: {
      myParentParam: 'some_other_value'
    }
  }
});
service.resolve(route).subscribe(res => {
  expect( ... )
  done();
});
});
```